# Android Screen moves to edit text that has focus

Tags: android, android-edittext

in my activity I have multiple edit texts, and some animated sliders with buttons beneath them. The problem is when I open a slider and tap on the button, the screen "jumps" back up to the first edit text. How can I stop this from happening? I just want the screen to stay where it was after the button press. Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT/UPDATE** I just played around with an iPhone. Would it rather be possible to remove focus from the edit text when the soft keyboard is minimized? (Removing the focus would work in regards to the original question of the screen navigating to the top by its self)

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your parent layout (i.e. LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc.)

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: Hi, I edited my question. I already have that so that the keyboard does not pop up automatically when I start the activity.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following solution. I created a method:

```
public void clearFocusOnEditText(){
    //editText.clearfocus()
}
```

I then added this method to my `ontouch()` and `onClick()` methods. I'm guessing this is not the best solution, but for all intents and purposes it works brilliantly.

Comment: Will only be able to accept this answer as the correct one in two days.

Answer (score -1):

add it in your manifest to the activity tag

```
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Comment: This does not remove the focus from the edit text when the keyboard is minimized. I need the focus to be removed when the user minimizes the soft keyboard.